# how to get process id from IAudioSessionManager2

Tags: winapi, core-audio

Background: enum all active sessions that are using system audio.

I am trying to get process information from IAudioSessionManager2. But I can't find such function. Does anyone know how to get it?

Sample code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368281(v=vs.85).aspx

IAudioSessionControl only provides such methods: GetDisplayName, but the display name I got is just null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [`IAudioSessionControl2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and the [`GetProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.